# finding all of different values in a column of a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

i have a mysql table like this :

```
+------+-------------+----------+
|  id  | name        | category |
+------+-------------+----------+
|    1 | product 1   |category-A| 
|    2 | product 2   |category-B| 
|    3 | product 3   |category-C| 
|    4 | product 4   |category-B| 
|    5 | product 5   |category-C|
|    6 | product 6   |category-A|
|    7 | product 7   |category-A|
|    8 | product 8   |category-C|
|    9 | product 9   |category-B|
+------+-------------+----------+
```

is there any function that returns sth like this?

```
category-A,category-B,category-C
```

note : new categories may be added later .

thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just looking for a unique list of all categories?

SELECT DISTINCT category FROM mytable

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category ORDER BY category) FROM TableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c57b/2)
- [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════════════════════════════════╗
║              RESULT              ║
╠══════════════════════════════════╣
║ category-A,category-B,category-C ║
╚══════════════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DISTINCT` in your query, it eliminate duplicate entry

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category )
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

SELECT DISTINCT columnName
FROM table_name

This should give you result containing all different values from that column.